# ¿Porque no funciona correctamente la comparación que estoy haciendo con strcmp?

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un buscador en el cual en una estructura definida, Se ingresan jugadores, cuando quiero "jugar", se le pidan 2 alias y con una comparación de strcmp compruebe si los jugadores se encuentran ingresados en el programa o no.

Para eso cree el código que les cito mas abajo.

los problemas que tengo son que me encuentra un solo jugador o peor aun, me encuentra ambos alias pero me guarda mal las posiciones en 'o' o 'l' mayormente la segunda posición me guarda un 0 o el mismo valor que 'o'.
Espero algún tipo de respuesta ya que soy principiante y necesito arreglar esto para un examen.

Si alguien se le ocurren ideas de que hice mal o tiene alguna otra forma de buscar/comparar ambos alias le agradecería muchísimo su aporte!
Ya que necesito entregar este trabajo para mi carrera.
Saludos.

````
//Estructura del programa
struct jugador {
    char alias  [6];
    char nombre [21];
    char apellido [21];
    int cedula ;
    int monto;
    int edad;
}j[10]; 

//opcion jugar (fragmento de codigo)
// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::   Jugar   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        case ('j'): case ('J'): {
            system ("cls");
            int m=0, o=0, l=0, n=0;
            o=0; 
            l=0;
            saldo1=0;
            saldo2=0;
            char alias1[5], alias2[5];
            cout << "Inserte alias del primer jugador: ";
            cin >> alias1;
            cout << "Inserte alias del segundo jugador: ";
            cin >> alias2;
            cout << "\n";
            
            while (m<2) {
                if (strcmp (j[o].alias, alias1)==0) { //Compara entre el alias ingresdo y los alias de la estrucutra
                    cout <<"\n"<<alias1 << " Encontrado con Exito."; 
                    strcpy (player1,alias1);         //si lo encuentra copia ese alias al jugador1 que es el primer jugador.
                    o -= 1;                          //Resta una posicion a 'o' porque luego hace o++
                    m++;                            
                }
                o++;
                if (strcmp (j[l].alias, alias2)==0) {   //hace lo mismo que el primer if pero con el segundo alias ongresado
                    cout <<"\n"<<alias2 << " Encontrado con Exito.\n\n";  //tienen que ser 2 alias ya que juegan 2 jugadores.
                    strcpy (player2,alias2);
                    l -= 1;                                  //aca busca en la posicion 'l'
                    m++; 
                }
                l++;
                if (o>10) {                                   //Si se pasa de 10, no encontro al alias y que cierre while ya que son solo 10 jugadores
                cout << "\n Alias: "<< alias1 <<" no encontrado";
                m++;
                }
                if (l>10) {
                cout << "\n Alias: "<< alias2 <<" no encontrado\n";
                m++;
                }       
            }
            cout << "\nO: " << o << "\nL: " << l; //Imprime posicion de 'o' y 'l' es para verificar la posicion.
            system ("PAUSE"); ```
````

Comment: Un error de indices, los if condicionales `if(l>10)`, `if(o>10)`, deberian tener como limite `variable > 9` debido a que con `> 10` haces que se alcance a tomar el valor 10 como indice y esto significa que estas iterando en la posición 10 de tu arreglo de jugadores, lo cual es incorrecto debido a que, sí, tiene 10 espacios, pero por indices solo puedes iterar hasta la posición 9. Esto podría estar generando algun error relacionado con las comparaciones.

Comment: Depura tu programa y verás el problema más sencillo. En la primera iteración del `while`, la `o` vale `0`, comparas con el elemento `0`, y si coincide restas `1` a `o` y luego le sumas `1`. Con lo que en la segunda vuelta vuelve a valer `0` y comparas con el mismo elemento. Revisa tu diseño porque me parece que no tiene sentido. Y te recomiendo poner nombres a las cosas con sentido. Hace más sencillo encontrar errores. Variables como `o` (que encima se parece a un `0`), `m`, `l`... Propenso a errores.

Comment: ¿[tag:c] o [tag:c++]? La respuesta depende del lenguaje que estés usando.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por los aportes, seria el lenguaje de c++.
Ya probé cambiando las condiciones de los if a > 9 y eso no arreglo nada.
Voy a intentar re diseñar el buscador de nuevo, si se les ocurre otra idea o aporte se los agradecería. Gracias!